# Can't create new forest on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows

I'm facing a problem creating a new forest on Windows Server 2008.

In the configuration steps I need to add a DNS server and I have two options. In the first one, the wizard will create a dimanic static address, but in all tutorials I found, always the second option is selected.

In this second one, you need to configure by yourself.  But when I click on the second option, nothing happens...

[image]

Comment: Don't use `.local` or MDMarra will hunt you down and force you to watch SCCM error logs all day.

Answer (score 2):

The 2nd option?  You mean clicking "No" to "Do you want to continue?"  Of course it's going to stop and do nothing then.

See here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754463%28WS.10%29.aspx

It's a normal message if this is a brand new forest without existing DNS.  It's basically telling you "hey I tried to find existing DNS to create a delegation and couldn't...are you cool with that?"  If it is a new forest, then the answer is "Yes, I'm cool with that...continue on mighty wizard"

From the actual technet article:

> A delegation for this DNS server cannot be created because the
>   authoritative parent zone cannot be found or it does not run Windows
>   DNS server. If you are integrating with an existing DNS
>   infrastructure, you should manually create a delegation to this DNS
>   server in the parent zone to ensure reliable name resolution from
>   outside the domain “treyresearch5.net”. Otherwise, no action is
>   required. If you are not concerned that people in other domains or on the Internet will not resolve DNS name queries for computer names in the local domain, you can disregard the message and click Yes.